# Share encrypted drive - decrypt client-side

Tags: sftp, file-sharing

I have an sftp server and an encrypted drive that I want to share.
Even though sftp is secure, I don't want the unlocked drive or the key to stay on the server.
So, I'd like to pull the encrypted disk data from the server and decrypt it myself client-side. Is there a way to do ths?

Comment: What OS is the server running?

Comment: dietpi, currently

Comment: I think that's a use case for iSCSI. If you need client to do the decryption, encrypt entire drive with LUKS and make the encrypted device available. Note that such device can't be accessed by multiple clients simultaneously.

Comment: that sounds interesting, thank you